# center two divs horizontally in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs (one under the other) and I want this column aligned centrally. But using `justify-content: center` the divs are aligned centrally along the y-axis (vertically) but not along the x axis (horizontally).

I would like to know if the only way (with flexbox) to also have center-align along the x-axis is to add `margin: auto`.

```
<div id="sharesocial">
  <div id="sharecondividi">
    Condividi
  </div>
  <div id="shareicons">
    <a target="blank" href=""><span class="fa fa-twitter-square" id="twitterbt"></span></a>
    <a target="blank" href=""><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square" id="googleplusbt"></span></a>
    <a target="blank" href=""><span class="fa fa-facebook-square" id="facebookbt"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sharesocial {
 background: #646464 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100px;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 174px;
}

#sharecondividi {
 align-self: center;
 color: #fff;
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
}

#shareicons {
 align-items: center;
 background: #f0f0f0 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: flex;
 height: 50%;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 95%;
}
```

Here jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uLah0gqa/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `flex-direction` is `column` you could use `justify-content` for vertical alignment *and `align-items` for horizontal alignment*.

Try this:

```
#sharesocial {
    align-items: center;
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uLah0gqa/1/)

Learn more:

- [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)